# Почему в середине raw-строки не может быть четное количество обратных слешей совместно с "(')

Tags: python

Например следующий код не выдаст ошибки:

```
 rs = r'Cat\'s home'
```

А этот код выдаст:

```
rs = r'Cat\\'s home'
```

То же самое, так ошибки не будет:

```
 rs = r'Cat\\\'s home'
```

А этот код выдаст:

```
rs = r'Cat\\\\'s home'
```

И так далее...

Этот факт я запомнил, но почему так получается не понимаю

Comment: можно внешние кавычки другие использовать: `r"Cat\\'s home"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ пользователя @Vitalts дан про обычные строки.
В raw строках (строки, предназначенные для регулярных выражениях) правила обработки слешей несколько другие.

---

Из [спецификации языка Питон](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> Even in a raw literal, quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the
>   backslash remains in the result; for example, r"\"" is a valid string
>   literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote;
>   r"\" is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an
>   odd number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw literal cannot end in
>   a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following
>   quote character).

Перевод:

> Даже в raw строковых константах, кавычки можно экранировать с помощью
>   слеша, но слеш остаётся в результате, например, `r'\''` является
>   верной строковой константой, состоящей из двух символов: слеш и
>   кавычка. `r'\'`— не является корректной константой (даже raw строки не
>   могут оканчиваться  нечётным кол-вом слешей, так как слеш экранирует
>   закрывающую кавычку).

При этом несмотря на то, что слеш экранирует кавычки, он не выкидывается из строки; то же происходит и для последовательности из двух слешэй.

---

Таким образом, этот ответ все же пересекается с ответом @Vitalts:

```
r'a\'
```

`EOL while scanning string literal`: Строка не закончилась, так как последняя кавычка экранирована и является частью строки.

```
r'a\\'
```

Всё хорошо: строка закончилась, так как первый слеш экранирует второй.

```
r'\\\'
```

Далее по аналогии...

---

```
r'1 \' 2'
```

Всё ок: кавычка в середине экранирована.

```
r'1 \\' 2'
```

Первый слеш экранировал второй, после чего строка закончилась. Теперь `2'` уже не относится к строке, отсюда `invalid syntax`

Comment: А какая разница? (добавил в ответ про середину)

Comment: Похоже действительно- никакой.

Comment: Все, я все понял! Закрывайте вопрос

Comment: Вопрос ваш, вам и закрывать. А на самом деле не закрывать, а ставить зеленую галку рядом с ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что обратный слеш - спец символ, который требуется экранировать вторым обратным слешем. Одинарная кавычка, в данном случае, также требует экранирование обратным слешем (поскольку она используется для выделения строки, если строку обрамите двойными кавычками, то в строке одинарная не требует экранирования и наоборот)

Здесь вы обратным слешем экранируете одинарную кавычку

```
rs = r'Cat\'s home'
```

Здесь же появляется еще один обратный слеш, который требуется экранировать еще одним.

```
rs = r'Cat\\'s home'
```

Здесь же вы экранировали и второй слеш

```
rs = r'Cat\\\'s home'
```

А здесь добавили еще один слеш, который также требуется экранировать

```
rs = r'Cat\\\\'s home'
```

Comment: Вроде бы это объяснение не для raw-строк